# Trying to change int value inside function in Python

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python and I am trying to change the value of an integer while inside of a function. Is there an easy way to do this? I haven't been able to find much on the subject. Here is my base code.

```
i = 0
numbers = [2, 7, 8, 14, 15, 38, 27, 9, 77, 10]

print("the value of [5] before the function call is " + str(numbers[5]))

def printArray(numbers, i):
    numbers[5] = 48
    numbers[0] = 50
    
    for x in numbers:
        print(x)
    
    i = 50
    
printArray(numbers, i)

print("The new value of i is " + str(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def printArray(numbers, i):
    ...
    i = 50
```

This creates `i` as a new *local* variable inside the function.  It does *not*, as you found, change the value of `i` in the caller.

Either make `i` a global variable, or return a value from the function and assign `i` to that value in the caller.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Still wrapping my head around some stuff and this just went right over my head.